# Python - Unable to import sklearn, but works fine for other packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy

Following is the error message I see, can you please let me know what's wrong?

```
Error Message: importerror: dll load failed: the specified procedure could not be found
```

The environment details:

- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- Python 3.7.1
- Numpy 1.19.0
- Scipy 1.1.0
- Threadpoolctl 2.1.0
- Joblib 0.16.0
- Scikit-learn(sklearn) 0.23.1

The command from python terminal: `from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error`

This is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 171, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 24, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 271, in <module>
    from ._minimize import *
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 21, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Did you try uninstalling `scipy` and installing again `pip uninstall scipy` and `pip install scipy` again? Seems like the issue is with the scipy library.

Comment: Yes, I did try uninstalling and reinstalling. No luck!